# Call function several times with different parameters

Tags: python

I have this csv File (the original file is larger and have more begin end parts):

```
global_begin;
config_file_name;namecsv
config_version;1.0
ch_number;2
index_assign;tgtindex
global_end;
src_db_begin;
src_db_ipaddress;157
src_db_servername;herz
src_db_type;postgres
src_db_ primary_index;src_ch_id
src_db_end;
tgt_db_begin;
```

Now I would like to call it several times via a function. The parameters always have a different name and also the return name should always be different.

```
def function1(begin, end):
    with open ('test3a.csv', encoding="latin-1") as csvfile:
        func_dict = dict()
        for line in csvfile:
            line = line.rstrip().rstrip(";")
            if line.endswith(begin):
                pass
            elif line.endswith(end):
                break
            else:
                key, value = line.split(";")
                func_dict[key] = value
                #print(value)
        return func_dict

global_dict = function1('global_begin', 'global_end')
source_dict = function1('src_db_begin', 'src_db_end')
```

What am I doing wrong with the handover and/or the call?

Comment: This doesn't look like a csv file. And it's not clear what you mean when you say you'd like to "call" it several times.

Comment: Yes this file is not comma seperated. By this I mean that I call the function several times with different parameters. In my post the function calling with global_dict and source_dict